# HTML/JavaScript RunTime Error

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

I'm struggling to figure this out since two days.. No luck... I need some help.

The error that I am getting if it is of any use:

**Webpage error details:**

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 03:04:49 UTC


Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 54
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/dvasa/Desktop/RE_USE/Compliance/Final.html
```

I'm basically trying to write some HTML text with Images tags et all to a TextArea.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX!!</title>
      <h2>Autoz!!</h2>
   </head>
<body>

<form name="lazForm">

    <input type="hidden" name="piced">
    <button onclick="picFunction()">PiC-It!!!</button><br>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="truarea" id="truarea"></textarea>    

</form> 



<script>


function picFunction()
{

var lazdata = window.parent.Decrypt.document.myForm.realacc.value;
var k;
var a;
var tab0, tab1 , tab2 ;
tab0 = '\<img src = "C:\\Users\\dvasa\\Desktop\\RE_USE\\Compliance\\Images\\0.png">'; 
tab1 = '\<img src = "C:\\Users\\dvasa\\Desktop\\RE_USE\\Compliance\\Images\\1.png">'; 


document.lazForm.piced.value= lazdata
a = document.lazForm.piced.value
var ary = lazdata.match(/.{1,1}/g);


for (var k=0;k<16;k++)
    {



if (ary[k] == "0")
  {
  document.getElementById( "truarea" ).innerHTML += tab0;

  }

else if (ary[k] == "1")
  {
  document.getElementById( "truarea" ).innerHTML += tab1; 

  } 


else 
  {
  document.getElementById( "truarea" ).innerHTML += ""; 

  } 



    }    

}

   </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

That's the entire code.

Is there any fix for this? IE gives no clues as to what the error is...

BTW, I'm totally new to Javascript. So, please excuse me if this is a silly Question.

Thanks!

Comment: document.getElementById( "truarea" ).innerHTML += tab0;

Answer (score 0):

you search the element by id which it doesnt have therefore your getELementByID returns undefined .
add id attribute to your truarea.

EDIT:

try adding method='post' to your form

Comment: I don't think that should be problem. I have included it anyway and the problem persists..

Comment: I don't think that should be problem. I have included it anyway and the problem persists..

I think it is related to suppression of some characters that are present in the url...  Like for instance in SQL , we use an ESCAPE character when the search string has a '%' or '_' .

Comment: it actually is a problem. you cannot find an element by id if it doesnt have id. if you have added id and the ptoblem persists, please update your question

Comment: Updated as suggested!  Thanks.

Comment: Got it working by accessing the InnerHTML.. Thanks !